# Add Field to Query

Tags: sql

How do i add  "Name" field to this query

```
    SELECT Address, 
           COUNT(*) AS CountOf
      FROM dbo.myDB
     WHERE Address IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY Address
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

ive tried

```
SELECT Name, 
       Address ...
```

But that come back with an error

Thanks,

Comment: Did you actually read the error?  It tells you exactly what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: Add it to the group by clause too.

Comment: Which RDBMS? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL...?

Comment: @RobbieDee I think it doesn't matter

Comment: @MegaTron It might actually matter as MySQL for example in some cases allows columns in the select that are not in the group by clause, but then the OP shouldn't have gotten any error so it's probably some other database.

Comment: @MegaTron This doesn't appear to be an abstract SQL question - some RDBMS is throwing an error when the code is run. GROUP BY behaviour also differs between SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: It's important to realize *why* simply adding Name isn't allowed here.  What use would Name be when there are potentially many different names to an Address?  You can pick the first name if you want, but it isn't entirely useful unless you know it makes sense.. (can two different people share the same address?).  You *probably* mean to add Name in group by.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the name as a column, you have to **add it to the `group by`** too or include it in an **aggregate function**:

```
SELECT
Address, Name, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
FROM dbo.myDB
WHERE Address IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Address, Name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the field `Name` to the SELECT and to the GROUP BY

```
SELECT
Address, Name, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
FROM dbo.myDB
WHERE Address IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Address, Name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
Address, MAX(Name) NAME, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
FROM dbo.myDB
WHERE Address IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Address
HAVING COUNT(*)>1

SELECT
Address, MIN(Name) NAME, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
FROM dbo.myDB
WHERE Address IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Address
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: Can you explain what the query does?

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question!  Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.

Answer (score -3):

How is the table you are trying to access? If you don't have a field name you can call it on the query
Edit: I didn't see the group by. If you have a group by clause every field on the select must be on the group by too (except formula like avg, sum...)